# Why is my data not being saved inside the class objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

> This is my header file ,it contains the class definition

```
class books {
public:
    books() = default; // this is to create an object | so class obj
    books(string name, string auth, double pri, int copy) {
        book_name = name;
        author = auth;
        price = pri;
    };



    int sell_books();
    bool status();


    


    int zero_copies(int c);
    void book_search(string name, string author);
    void buy_book(string name,string auth,double money);
    void print_();

    
    bool data{};
    double price{};
    string book_name{};
    string author{};
    int copy{};
     
private:
    
    //ClassName ObjectName[number of objects];

};

int books::sell_books() {


    std::cout << "type in the name of your book " << std::endl;
    getline(cin>>ws,book_name);
    std::cout << "type in the name of your author " << std::endl;
    getline(cin >> ws,author );
    std::cout << "type in the price that you want for it " << endl;
    cin >> price;
    std::cout << "type in the number of copies you want to sell " << endl;
    cin >> copy;

    return 1; //function will return 1 to show that it is succesful








}



void books::print_() {

    cout << std::endl;
    cout << "This is the book name : " << book_name << endl;
    cout <<"This is the new author " <<  author << endl;
    cout <<"This is the price " << price << endl;
    cout << std::endl;


}

int maximum(int a, int b) {

    if (a > b) {
        return a;
    }
    else {
        return b;
    }
}
void books::book_search(string name, string auth) {

    int a = name.length();
    int b = (book_name).length();
    int result = maximum(a, b);
    for (int i = 1; i < result; ++i) {
        int k = strncmp(name.c_str(), (book_name).c_str(), i);
        
    }



}
void books::buy_book(string name ,string auth, double money) {
    if (book_name == name) {

        cout << "book found " << endl;
        cout << "this is the price " << price << endl;
        int value = zero_copies(copy);
        if (value = 0) {
            if (money > price) {

                money = money - price;
                std::cout << "this is your account balance " << money << endl;
            }
            else if (money < price) {

                cout << "there is not enough money " << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (value == 1) {
            cout << "book no found " << endl;
        }
    }


}
int books::zero_copies(int c) {
    int k{};
    if (c == 0) {

        cout << "there are no copies remaining " << endl;
        k = 1;
    }
    else if (c > 1) {

        std::cout << endl;
        k= 0;
    }
    return k;
}


bool books::status() {
    
    if (book_name == "") { //if the book name of that object is null then we shall return false
        
        if (author == "") {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (book_name != "") {
        
        
        if (author != "") {
            return true;
        }

    }

}




int choice{0};

void menu_func() {
    
    std::cout << "MENU" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1 . sell your books " << '\n' << " 2 . buy your books " << "3 . check your account balance " << endl;
    std::cout << "choose your options " << endl; 
    cin >> choice;
    
    

}
```

> Now this is my main cpp file ,here i will show you the code

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double balance{24.54};
    menu_func();



    books store[10]{}; 


    int i{ 0 };

    switch (choice) {
    case 1: {

        char reply;
  //address of class is null
         
        while (true) { 
            if (store[i].status() == false) { //false means that there is no data inside them
               
                store[i].sell_books();
                balance = balance + store[i].price;  //*(store)[i].price
                std::cout << "do you want to continue " << std::endl;
                cin >> reply;
                if (reply == 'Y') {
                    ++i;
                    continue;
                }

                if (reply == 'N') {
                    cout << "Balance " << balance << endl;
                    break;
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (reply == 'B') {

                    cout << "Going back to main menu " << endl;
                    menu_func();
                }
            }
            else if(store[i].status() == true) {
                
                    ++i;
                    continue;
                    if (i == 10) {

                        cout << "you have reached the end of the file " << endl;
                        break;
                    }

                
            }
            // the program usually stops at the i 









        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            std::cout << std::endl;
            cout << "This is at index " << i << endl;
            store[i].print_();
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        break;
    }
```

> The program works it allows me to type into the member variables of the object however it is not saved ,it will reset after debug time.I want it to stay inside that object until i let it go myself.

I tried to make the member variables a pointer to point to an adress of another member variable.But that turned out to be a hassle.I couldn't really find what i was looking for online

Comment: Do you mean that you want your objects to persist between program runs?

Comment: Don't tag questions about C++ with the C tag.  It annoys people and attracts downvotes.

Comment: @AndyG yes ,i want the data that i store ,to be saved no matter how many times i run the program.I don't want it to reset .

Comment: Please show a [mre] in your question.  This code [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/zed75T1fY).  What is `menu_func()`?  What is `choice`?

Comment: @EkeneNwokedi You will want to do some research into *serialization*

Comment: Do you have compiler warnings enabled?  Did your compiler warn you about `if (value = 0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to "Why is the my data not being saved inside the class objects?" between runs of the program is: programs don't work that way. Each time a program starts, it starts fresh.

Any program that you've used that ever seems to save data between runs is doing that by saving the data outside of the program's memory and then reloading it the next time it's run.

A basic way of doing this is saving to and loading from a file. As a comment notes, research further with the term "serialization".